# Data from API rendering as empty (array/object issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a components that aims to display data from API:

```
class Item extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    output: []
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3005/products/157963')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ output: data }));
  }


render() {
    console.log(this.state.output);
  return (
    <ItemPanel>
    <ItemBox>
    <BoxTitle>{this.state.output}</BoxTitle>
  </ItemPanel>
  );
  }
 export default Item;
```

console.log(this.state.output) returns proper data, while my component won't render, its throwing this error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, general, brand, images}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I guess the data from api is an object. I have tried using JSON.parse or toString() already :/

This is output from console:
[image]

Comment: can you share what `this.state.output` it consoles? what exactly you want to show in  `<BoxTitle>` from `id, general, brand, images` ?

Comment: Let;s try to show brand here, console.log is above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are displaying whole object in `<BoxTitle>`, Let's try to show brand here. I have update the code given in question.
Updated initial state `output []` to `{}`

```
class Item extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    output: {}
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3005/products/157963')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ output: data }));
  }


render() {
    console.log(this.state.output);
  const { brand = {name : ""} } = this.state.output // added default name until we get actual value
  return (
    <ItemPanel>
    <ItemBox>
    <BoxTitle>{brand.name}</BoxTitle>
  </ItemPanel>
  );
  }
 export default Item;
```

Comment: Small fix was needed here: { brand = {name = ""} } -> { brand= {name: ""} }, and it is working now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `<ItemBox>` is not closed should be `<ItemBox/>`

Comment: Im now struggling to access images from that api, have tried 
const { images = {primary:""} } = this.state.output;
and a few variations, but still cant load image src. Help appreciated

Comment: try this, `const { brand = {name : ""} , images: {primary: {...}} = this.state.output`

Answer (score 0):

While your component fetches from your API it renders the element tree described in the render function.

Initial state for `output` is an empty array and that's a good start.

You should consider what to display to your application user when loading data from the API or if the network request fails.

I'm quite sure that you don't want to render the object returned upon a successful API call as-is.

That said, `JSON.stringify` function can be used for viewing what result is set in state upon a successful API call before picking what fields will be displayed, how and where they are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can better use conditional rendering,

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.output);
  return (
    <ItemPanel>
     <ItemBox>
     {
       if(this.state.output.brand.name !=== null) ?
         <BoxTitle>{this.state.output.brand.name}</BoxTitle> :
       <BoxTitle>Brand Name is Empty</BoxTitle>
     }
    </ItemPanel>
  );
  }
```